# Highcharts Animation after scrolling not working

Tags: animation, highcharts

I want an animated chart like this: see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2qsuvnpk/2/)

this is the code:

```
animation: {
            defer: 1500,
            duration: 1000
            }
```

but the animation should be started when the chart is visible after scrolling, not when the page is loaded. To achieve this I added code as shown in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/appear/)

But after that the animation does not work properly: see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2qsuvnpk/)

And embedded in a website it does not work at all: https://www.rnd.de/politik/bundestagswahl-den-volksparteien-droht-2021-das-ende-ZOMR37364VFJ7PCOSMGVHMEWO4.html

it is possible to use this method with highcharts in iframes?

And another question: Is it possible to first hide the data labels of a series too and display it later like the bars?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, You have async data and that is why the animation doesn't work ine the way that you expected. As a solution you can load data independently from scroll position and then render the chart synchronously when it is visible.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek How can I load data independently?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about async data. The problem is related with multiple series and `H.erase` method. Example with different solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y05jpwgc/

Comment: thank you, @ppotaczek, it works in this case. But it does worl not in another. Here you see the wanted [animation](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2ujw46p1/3/) When I add your code I get this [result](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2ujw46p1/4/). Do you know why? And I am afraid it does not work [embedded](https://www.rnd.de/politik/bundestagswahl-den-volksparteien-droht-2021-das-ende-ZOMR37364VFJ7PCOSMGVHMEWO4.html)

Comment: The animation seems to be the same. Could you describe the differences?

Comment: sorry, the link to the animation was wrong. Here is the correct [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2ujw46p1/7/)

Comment: The animation from the link also looks correct. Please specify the problem.

Comment: I want to fire this [animation](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2ujw46p1/7/) after scrolling down. But when I add your code and some text the animation does not start: see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/2ujw46p1/4/)

Comment: Sorry, but both animations work fine for me. Animation 1: https://gifyu.com/image/1xFF Animation 2: https://gifyu.com/image/1xYq

Comment: in my case it looks a bit different: [gif](https://gifyu.com/image/1Kf7)

Comment: I have found an error in a console, which maybe caused the different behaviour. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xcewzs2d/

Comment: same result: the animation does not start, but thank you for trying!

Comment: Another try: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5p4ojqzd/ I noticed that result is the same as yours if it doesn't scroll to the very bottom.

Comment: Now the animation works fine in fiddle! Is it possible to achieve this effect with an [embedded chart](https://www.rnd.de/gesundheit/covid-19-tote-amtliche-zahl-erklart-ubersterblichkeit-nur-zum-teil-MSKIYYLEEZAS7LAA2O6DC4Y6N4.html) as well?

Comment: That's a great info! There must be some difference between the code you are using, because the chart should work in the same way in both places.

Comment: The code is exactly the same but on my computer the animation of the embedded chart is fired on load: [gif](https://gifyu.com/image/Ag2H) Do you get a different result? [link](https://www.rnd.de/gesundheit/covid-19-tote-amtliche-zahl-erklart-ubersterblichkeit-nur-zum-teil-MSKIYYLEEZAS7LAA2O6DC4Y6N4.html)

Comment: I have the same result, but there must be some difference between the jsfiddle example and the embeded chart. Please try to add more code from the page and reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/3q5pjcmr/2/) with exactly the code of the embedded chart on this [page](https://www.rnd.de/gesundheit/covid-19-tote-amtliche-zahl-erklart-ubersterblichkeit-nur-zum-teil-MSKIYYLEEZAS7LAA2O6DC4Y6N4.html) I only added some text to achive the animation effect. In case of the fiddle it works totally fine, but it does not in case of the embedded chart. There must be some other reason.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the fact that you are using iframe for the chart. Please try to change the target of scroll event listener to: `window.parent.addEventListener` like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/508qpLmy/

Comment: I did change it but the chart disappeared. I do not see the chart in your fiddle either.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce the main problem in jsfiddle by using `iframe`. Is it possible for you to test out if resign of using iframe resolves the problem?